# REST api for Azure DataLake Storage Service Principal not possible to use folder-specific access

Tags: azure, rest, active-directory, azure-storage

I'm trying to configure folder-specific access to adls (gen2) storage using app registration (active directory/service principal) auth. It works well when I'm using RBAC configuration to the whole storage/container, but I still got a 403 error when I'm configuring the access (read+execute) even to the root folder.
Here are the steps I did during my configuration:

1. I created app registration, create a secret for it and add an API permission to blob storages and adls:
   [image]
2. In the root directory of my storage account the I add the ACL (Access control list) for Read and Execute access.[image]
3. Using postman I got the Oauth token for my application and trying to execute a GET request for the container to get the list of files in the directory using the URL from the azure docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/list) :
   [image]

And got the error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "AuthorizationPermissionMismatch",
        "message": "This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.\nRequestId:12401499-f01f-0105-2a98-327246000000\nTime:2021-04-16T08:15:07.8676657Z"
    }
}
```

And it works when I set RBAC (IAM) access to the whole container instead of ACL. What should I also add in my configuration to use folder-specific access for the service principal account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can also reproduce your issue on my side, from your request url, you want to do operation `List /abc/d/`, so to solve the issue, you need to give the ACL permissions like below.

| Operation | / | abc/ | d/ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| List /abc/d/ | `--X` | `--X` | `R-X` |

You have already given the `R-X`(actually`--x` is enough) permission at the container( i.e. `/`), so you just need to give `--X` at `abc` directory and `R-X` at `d` directory, then it will work fine.

To give the ACL permissions to the directory, refer to the screenshot below.

[image]

See reference - [Common scenarios related to ACL permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-access-control#common-scenarios-related-to-acl-permissions), your case is the same as the last one.

[image]

Test(The command essentially calls the REST API you used):

[image]

[image]

Comment: I see, it also required to provide RWX access to every file in the folder.. Not handy enough, but it helped. Thank you